# Extend JavaExec task with additional configuration on the classpath

Tags: gradle

I have a task of type JavaExec that does a lot of complicated steps in order to compile & run the application. This task is generated by a plugin outside of my control.

I want to create another task that "extends" this task, adding an extra dependency configuration. This configuration stores some dependencies that should only be included for this specific task.

Is there an easy way for me to create such a task, or do I have to copy over all configuration properties (which may change at any time) manually?